# Sketchup to Unreal Engine, overlapping issue

Tags: light

What i wanna do is import my sketchup's projects to unreal engine, but when i do this, the lightmap UV are overlapping. In an another site they told me to import the projects into Blender using the exported .DAE format, edit UV and export as FBX format. But i don't know how to edit the UV.. Is there a tutorial or something similar who can help me?

Comment: this site is a Q&A support, a tutorial request is offtopic... If you search the internet, there are so many different tutorials... come back here if you have troubles following some of them, with specific issues (one per post)

Answer (score 0):

First - You can set object to dynamic in UE and forgot about lightmap UV

Second - If you need only static Meshes:

a) check which channel using in UE - usually 1, 0 for material (but it customizable);

b) repair this channel in Blender (because this site is dedicated for it):

b1) delete uv info from this and create smart uv project (in most case it's enough), or you can do it manually: tons of info [here](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=W6ImWo7MIsyg6ATWuI6YAQ&q=blender+correct+overlapping+uvs&oq=blender+correct+overlapping+uvs&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7344.8952.0.9048.7.7.0.0.0.0.78.475.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.yzR_2rp9mFk)

keep in mind that light UV need to UE for applying shading texture after baking